# Running report gives me a 404

Tags: wordpress, reports

Having a very odd error with a CiviCRM install on wordpress. Every seems to be working (membership signup, looking up people, etc.) except running reports.

1. Click on report URL
2. View report options, then select "Refresh Results"
3. Page loads "No Results Found"

If I add &reset=1 to the end of the report, it works correctly

CiviCRM 5.15.0
Wordpress 5.2.2–en
PHP 7.2 on hosted service

Comment: When you say "click on report url", are these links that have been manually added to the menu?

Comment: No, any report does this, even the built in ones.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the error seemed to be related to partial upgrade I had (the SQL upgrade had worked, but the system hadn't changed the version number back from .upgrade, so it thought it wasn't finished). Once I fixed that, this problem went away.